# Extreme value theory: asymptotic of the least-rolled number out of a series of rolls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, dice, extreme-value-analysis

Choose positive integers $D$ and $N$. Roll a fair $D$-sided die $N$ times, recording the number of times each of the $D$ outcomes are rolled, say $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_D.$ What are the asymptotics of $\min(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_D)$?

They're not independent, so I can't directly apply the [Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem) but that's probably a good starting point.

If it makes it easier you can assume $N \gg D.$ Of course the leading term is $N/D$ but what’s the second-order term? Maybe $\asymp \sqrt{N/D}$?

Comment: This corresponds to the minimum of a uniform multinomial. Does notlook easy. See eg https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/13/11/2173
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-21/issue-3/Distribution-of-Maximum-and-Minimum-Frequencies-in-a-Sample-Drawn/10.1214/aoms/1177729800.full